# Standard Deviation in a Powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, stdev

I'm moving my coworker's static data to a powerpivot that updates daily and is connected to an access database. I've been able to move all of it just fine, except for the standard deviation part. I need to find the standard deviation of the calls column for the same day of the week for the last 3 weeks. I need to be able to carry this throughout the table. I included a copy of the table I'm working with. The calls column is to the right but I was unable to include it because rules. It's just titled "calls". Any help would be appreciated.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwzb8.png)